# What is the Golang equivalent of Node's NODE_ENV

Tags: node.js, templates, go, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up templating whereby based on an environment variable to indicate whether we are in a development, staging or production environment, the HTML that is rendered is pointed towards different servers.

To do this I would like to use something like Node does in the NODE_ENV environment variable, and then conditionally set the path based on that in my code.

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  /* development code */
} else {
  /* production code */
}
```

Is there a standard for defining an environment in Golang? Does this seem like a logical approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a logical approach.  In fact it's a somewhat standard practice when deploying servers.

There is no standard in the go world, so do whatever.

Just try to keep it obvious, ie: `APP_ENV=dev`

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to an equivalent of `NODE_ENV` in the Go world. You can set an environment variable `APP_ENV` in your IDE locally (and in production).

```
env := os.Getenv("APP_ENV")
if env == "production" {
  /* production-version of the code */
} else {
  /* development-version of the code */
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can still using "NODE_ENV"， it's just a name, then use os.Getenv("NODE_ENV")get it.

Comment: `NODE_END` is used for Node-based applications. Using it for Go applications may cause unwanted behaviors.